# AWS Lambda needs access to multiple VPCs

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

We have 2 VPCs: 1 for staging/testing and one for production.

I have a lambda that executes fine against either staging or production -- the only difference is configuration. Unfortunately, I get a DNS lookup error when I execute the prod trigger inside my staging VPC; which makes sense.

The question is: How can it up so that my lambda can access both VPCs? Please don't tell me I have to copy & paste the lamdba and change the role.

**Clarification**

My lamdba is driven by a periodic trigger. It merely makes a webservice call and checks the results of the payload and submits the value as cloudwatch metrics; the same service operates in staging and prod and the only difference is (should be) the url `http://service.prod` and `http://service.stage`

The 2 VPC's don't need to talk to each other. I can access both URLs from my desktop; I need that same functionality

Comment: Just to confirm... Do you want the same Lambda function to operate in both environments simultaneously (calling resources in both VPCs)? It is normally advisable to totally separate these environments to ensure the Test environment cannot access your Production environment. If you can expand on your situation and use-case, we would be in a better position to offer a solution. (Several ideas spring to mind, but it depends on your need.)

Comment: Some would argue that it is not an optimal design to  allow prod and staging to be able to cross-connect.  But, if that's the objective, have you considered [peering the VPCs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-peering.html)?  It's not clear from the question what kind of DNS lookup is failing, or exactly why. Is there a private hosted zone involved?

Comment: Updated for clarity

Comment: Unfortunately  lambda can access resources only in 1 VPC.  
To support your use case you can do the following:
Create 2 lambda functions, 1 for each VPC. 
Create 1 lambda that would accept triggers and act as a "main" function. It would need to have access to both VPC functions.  Then in your code just calls each function when it's required.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up configuring the Lambda to work from within our development VPC which is the same as my laptop. So, when I said I wanted it to work just like my laptop, well, that's what I did.